# Possible to calculate multiple sums in the same rolling window in SQL?

Tags: sql, sum, rolling-computation

I have several columns which take the same partition and order by statements, and I would like to create a separate sum for each of them in a different column. I have an extremely inefficient way to do it, but was wondering if there was a clean way.

```
create table small_test_final_balances
select
    sum(Industrial_Spend) over (partition by account_id, 
    calendar_month order by trxn_timestamp desc rows unbounded 
    preceding) as industrial_sum,

    sum(Consumer_Spend) over (partition by account_id, calendar_month 
    order by trxn_timestamp desc rows unbounded preceding) as 
    cumulative_sum,
    *
from test1
```

As you can see the over statement remains the same for all, all that I am changing is which column I actually sum, and what that resultant column is called.

Comment: Your query is fine.

Comment: Extremely inefficient for large sizes. This is just a small example, but I would have to do 15 rolling sums. Each with the over and partition. Or would  that still work?

Comment: . . You have to do the rolling sums *anyway*, because you have different columns being aggregated.  Of course, optimizations depends on the database, but there is no reason to expect that the work done for partitioning and ordering the window would be repeated for all the sums.

Comment: "rows unbounded preceding" is the default value. No need to specify it.